# Como montar um layout com navbar flutuante em Bootstrap?

Tags: html

Estava tentando fazer um layout com menu flutuante, como no link abaixo:

https://demo.tagdiv.com/newspaper_nomad/

Porém sempre que tentou definir o posicionamento absoluto na navbar, para fazer com que ela flutue sobre o conteúdo, o layout da nav se desconfigura.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light container" style=" max-width:1400px;position:absolute;top:25px">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link">Home</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link">Home</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="conteudo">
       .conteudo_do_site
</div>
```

Funciona fazendo com que o conteúdo da página flutue com o z-index inferior, mas isso acaba gerando muitos bugs nas outras seções do site, assim seria mais interessante que a apenas a nav flutue

Como fazer isso com boostrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Bootstrap tem uma classe para fiz a barra, .fixed-top você usa essa classe junto da classe .navbar

Então ficaria assim no seu caso:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light container" style=" max-width:1400px;position:absolute;top:25px">
```

Não é uma boa prática usar css inline como esta usando. E tamtém não sei se é bom usar a classe .container na navbar, uma vez que a própria navbar já um tipo de container.

Mas posso estar errado.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Fiz um erro acima, "uma classe para fixar a barra", foi mal pelo erro de digitação.